# Is there any way to force an iPhone application to relaunch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, relaunch

Basically -[UIApplication openURL:] would be perfect, if it wasn't for the fact that it doesn't work within the same application (at least on simulator -- if this works on device someone please tell me).  It's not a super big deal though if it just relaunches w/o URLness since I can obviously just persist some data.  The goal of this is to essentially free all memory in the application and call all of the loading procedures.

Comment: Not that I know of. It sounds as if there is another problem if you even have to think about doing this.

Comment: Try posting something about the problem that makes you think this is the right thing to do; it's almost certainly not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You almost certainly could do this with the C library call `execv`. But like everybody else, I think it is wrong to even be thinking about it.

Comment: 2 things -- first of all, does anyone know if apple disabled execv on the device (like they do with mprotect)?  Secondly, when I try this in the simulator, it 'launches' the app and definitely calls main, but for some reason shows a black screen in the simulator.  Any ideas on this? I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good idea. You should fix your memory management issues and provide a reload button if the application pulls in external data sources.

If you absolutely need to do this, you can use `-[UIApplication openURL:]` to open a web page in Safari that redirects back to your application via an url scheme.

Comment: A game that I have used, Hyper Warp, does this exact thing - when it runs low on memory, it saves the game, opens a URL on their website, then opens the app reloads the game.

Technically, it's possible. But it was really, really irritating.

Comment: I would not knowingly purchase a game that behaved like that.